# How to remove text from an image

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, server-side

I am trying to remove text from images, like for example we have a screenshot of instagram post, now we tried to fetch only image from this screenshot, in our .NET/C# code we read all pixel and check its color to see if we are getting white space, so that we can remove all unused space and extract only picture, but it didn't worked as expected, Does anyone has idea to do it correctly?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

To extract text from image u need to use some OCR lib like Tesseract.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract

If necessary, u can use some type of image editor lib for .Net like AForge.

https://github.com/andrewkirillov/AForge.NET

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question. divide your problem into steps and start solving from the first step.

Best .Net library is EMGUCV, an OpenCV wrapper which is broadly used in image processing.

AForge.Net is another good one. Follow the documentation to process text data from images.

The logic is 
 1. Track texts in the image.
 2. if the font and size is similar and static, you can input fixed pattern and match patterns.
 3. Then there are several option to remove a found object (here you will find texts as object or area.)
 4. You have to tune after removing texts from the pictures. That will need image reconstruction algorithms. These all are available in EMGUCV.

Please see the documentation.